# algorithm for finding out pixel coordinates on a circumference of a circle

Tags: math, geometry, pixel

how do i find out pixel value at certain degree on the circumference of a circle if I know the pixel co-ordinates of the center of the circle, radius of the circle ,and perpendicular angle.
Basically, I am trying to draw the hands of a clock at various times ( 1 o clock , 2 o clock etc )

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Let `h` be the hour as a floating point number (`h=2.25` would be 02:15, etc.) between 0 and 12. `(cX,cY)` are the coordinates of the center. `hLength` and `mLength` are the lengths of the hour and min hands.

```
// Hour hand
hAngle = 2.0*Pi*h/12.0; // 0..12 mapped to 0..2*Pi
hX = cX + hLength * sin(hAngle);
hY = cY - hLength * cos(hAngle);

// Min hand
mAngle = 2.0*Pi*h; // 0..1 mapped to 0..2*Pi, etc.
mX = cX + mLength * sin(mAngle);
mY = cY - mLength * cos(mAngle);
```

Answer (score 9):

Where the centre of the circle is `(X0, Y0)`, the radius is `R` and the angle with the x-axis is theta:

```
X1 = (R * cos theta) + X0
```

and

```
Y1 = (R * sin theta) + Y0
```

Comment: This shouldn't be voted up so high. He doesn't appear to know the value of theta. The answer by Eric Bainville is more complete.

Comment: @jmucchiello - Not sure I understand you... we were asked for an algorithm and I gave the description of a function with formal parameters. At this stage, nobody knows the 'value' of theta! If you mean that I didn't calculate scaling factors for the motion of the hands of a clock, and the angle in radians for each of the hour ticks, you're absolutely right I didn't. I have work to do writing my own code!

Comment: Yeah , I guess I asked 2 questions in one. Your answer is perfect for the first part. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If (x1,y1) is a point on the circumference and (x,y) is the center, then `x1 = x + r * cos(angle)`  and `y1 = y + r * sin(angle)`

Comment: Note that this assumes the standard "mathematical" coordinate system, where Y increases upwards. In typical 2D computer graphics, that is inverted (to make Y grow with the address of the pixel).

Comment: This is only valid for a circle with center in origo.

Comment: Just add the coordinates of the centre.

Answer (score 0):

if center is at x0, y0, and 0,0 iz at bottom-left corner, then 1 o'clock is at x0 + r*sin(2π/3), y0+r*cos(2π/3).

Answer (score -1):

Draw lines from the center to coordinates computed with `sin` for the y coordinates and `cos` for the x coordinates (both multiplied by the length of the hand).

[Wikipedia has more information on how sin and cos "work"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Sine).